# How to show that the determinant of this matrix is in a nice product factorization,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, products

Show that

$$det
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & \cdots &1 \\
        \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & \cdots &\lambda_n \\
        \lambda^2_1 & \lambda^2_2 & \cdots &\lambda^2_n \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        \lambda^{n-1}_1 & \lambda^{n-1}_2 & \cdots &\lambda^{n-1}_n \\
\end{bmatrix}
=\prod_{n\ge i>j\ge1}(λ_i−λ_j)$$

My work so far,

I am trying to use induction on $n$.  For the base case n=2, the claim is true, since we have $(\lambda_2 - \lambda_1)$.

I'm not sure how to carry out the inductive step.

Any hints or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The matrix (or its transpose) is called the Vandermonde matrix. One proof of its determinant is given in the [article here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ut697c021ykbm2x/Vandermonde_matrix.pdf?dl=0).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Adding a scalar multiple of one column to another column leaves the determinant unchanged.

Use transformation $C_i=C_i-C_1, 2\le i\le n$ (leaving $(1,0,0,...0)$ in first row) and then try induction?

**Edit**: As mentioned in the other answer, the matrix is called Vandermonde Determinant and proof in lines of what I have mentioned above is there in [this proofwiki article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant) (Proof 1)

There a second operation, namely $a_{ij}=a_{ij}-x_1\times a_{i-1,j-1}$ after above transformation is used to prove $V_n=\prod_{k=2}^n (x_k-x_1)V_{n-1}$, where we know $V_{n-1}$ by induction hypothesis.

Comment: Hi @JessePFrancis, I have my first row now as [1 0 0 ... 0], with determinant unchanged, as you said.  Now, if I use the Laplace expansion and expand along the first row, the only non-zero contribution is 1* det[(nx1) x (nx1)] submatrix, from which I can apply the induction hypothesis.  Am I done?  Seems way too simple, I must have missed something...

Comment: @LebronJames, true, we hit roadblock. See the other answer.